# UIPickerView depending on first component

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uipickerview

So I have a UIPickerView with two components. The first one called "Cupboards", the second "Drawer". They have a one to many relationships in CoreData Cupboards <-->> Drawer. I would like that if I select a Cupboard, only the matching Drawers get displayed. I'm not sure how to get that working with the relationship.

That's what I have for showing the Cupboard:

```
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if(component==0){
                return cupboards.count
            }

     xxxx

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if(component==0){
        return cupboards[row].name
    }

    xxxx

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(component==0){

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

**Update:**

Got it like that now, but I get no results.

```
var cupboardDrawers = [Drawer]()

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(component==0){
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Drawer> = Drawer.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cupboard == %@", cupboards[row].name!)

        do{
            let result = try mgdContext.fetch(request)
            cupboardDrawers = result
            addEatDataPicker.reloadAllComponents()
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and update a cupboardDrawers array with the fetching results:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if(component==0){
        return cupboards.count
    } else { 
        return cupboardDrawers.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if(component==0){
        return cupboards[row].name
    } else {
        return cupboardDrawers[row].yourProperty
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if(component==0){
        // you can add this part to a separate function and call it here
        cupboardDrawers = []
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Drawer>(entityName:”Drawer”)
        request.predicate = YourPredicate with cupboards[row].name
        do {
            let items = context.fetch(request)
            guard items.count > 0 else {
                 print(“no items found”)
                 return 
            }
            cupboardDrawers = items
            //reload your picker
        } catch { 
              print(error) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you, I'm new to swift and not sure what I use instead of YourPredicate.  And cupboardDrawers should be `var cupboardDrawers = [Drawer]()` right?

Comment: You are welcome ;) yes it’s correct, the predicate depends on how you have set up your entity, for example it could be NSPredicate(format: “cupboard == %@“, cupboards[row].name)

Comment: hmm I get the `no items found` call

Comment: Try cupboard.name in your predicate, it depends on how you have set up your relationship.

Comment: Thank you so much, everything workes great :) But I have one more question. I created a function to create a new child object from a drawer, and to get the right drawer I created a new var `selectedDrawer = cupboardDrawers[row]` in the did select. The problem is that I get an `Index out of range` error - It works when I  create Cupboard 1 with 1 Drawer, Cupboard 2 with 2Drawers and so on. Is that an update thing of selectedDrawer or something else?

Comment: Great! ;) You are welcome! Your pickerView number of rows in component must have the same value as your cupboardDrawers count. That signify that probably the object you are looking for do not exist, print your array and check if is it empty.

Comment: I think that works, cause without the `selectedDrawer = cupboardDrawers[row]` everything works. And if I select Cupboard 3 with 2 Drawers the [row] is 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160439/discussion-between-sane-and-francesco-deliro).